# Decryption data using php rijndael-128 decryption

Tags: php

I'm trying to decrypt data in PHP, I tried this code, but it doesn't print "almost" nor the decrypted data nor "finish". It only prints this line "4b3b798e708d81a939ca084d387136145".

Here is my code :

```
    <?php

class MCrypt
{
    private $iv = 'fedcba9876543210'; #Same as in JAVA
    private $key = '0123456789abcdef'; #Same as in JAVA
    function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * @param string $str
     * @param bool $isBinary whether to encrypt as binary or not. Default is: false
     * @return string Encrypted data
     */
    function encrypt($str, $isBinary = false)
    {
echo "3";
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $str = $isBinary ? $str : utf8_decode($str);
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', ' ', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $encrypted = mcrypt_generic($td, $str);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $isBinary ? $encrypted : bin2hex($encrypted);
    }
    /**
     * @param string $code
     * @param bool $isBinary whether to decrypt as binary or not. Default is: false
     * @return string Decrypted data
     */
    function decrypt($code, $isBinary = false)
    {
echo "4";
        $code = $isBinary ? $code : $this->hex2bin($code);
        $iv = $this->iv;
        $td = mcrypt_module_open('rijndael-128', ' ', 'cbc', $iv);
        mcrypt_generic_init($td, $this->key, $iv);
        $decrypted = mdecrypt_generic($td, $code);
        mcrypt_generic_deinit($td);
        mcrypt_module_close($td);
        return $isBinary ? trim($decrypted) : utf8_encode(trim($decrypted));
    }
    protected function hex2bin($hexdata)
    {
echo "5";
        $bindata = '';
        for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($hexdata); $i += 2) {
            $bindata .= chr(hexdec(substr($hexdata, $i, 2)));
        }
        return $bindata;
    }
}
$encrypted="4b3b798e708d81a939ca084d387136";
echo $encrypted;
$mcrypt = new MCrypt();
echo "1";
$decrypted = $mcrypt->decrypt($encrypted);
echo "almost";
echo $decrypted;
echo "finish";
?>
```

Comment: Both your IV and key should probably be in binary form. As for how your Java app derives its key... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯